# Java custom button, extended Jcomponent - mouseListener not responding

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jcomponent

I am working on a platformer game for my final year on HS. I have recently decided to implement a HUD where I can pause, save or quit from the game.
I have successfully taken care of the classes, objects and drawings except for detecting the mouse events.

The `Button` class is a `private sub-class` of `Hud` class, it extends `JComponent` and implements `MouseListener`. All of the (required) MouseListener methods have also been implemented but they don't seem to trigger when there should be an even such as when the mouse is entering bounds of the `Button object`.

When googling about the issue, some answers were saying that `addMouseListener(this)` was missing from the class, but I have that already.

How do I make the `Button` class detect mouse events?
(i.e: hover or click)

This is what it looks like when i run the program:
[image]

## Hud.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Hud {
    
    private ArrayList<Button> Buttons;
    
    public Hud() {
        System.out.println("Hud created");
        init();
    }
        
    private void init() {
        Buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        Buttons.add(new Button(10,  10, 100, 40, "Save",    10, new Color(255,126,126), new Color(255,78,78),Color.WHITE));
        Buttons.add(new Button(115, 10, 100, 40, "Pause",   10, new Color(255,126,126), new Color(255,78,78),Color.WHITE));
        Buttons.add(new Button(220, 10, 100, 40, "Quit",    10, new Color(255,126,126), new Color(255,78,78),Color.WHITE));
        Buttons.add(new Button(Config.WINDOW_WH[0]-110, 10, 100, 40, "Settings", 10, new Color(255,126,126), new Color(255,78,78),Color.WHITE));
    }
    
    public void update() {
        for(Button b: Buttons)
            b.update();
        
    }
    
    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        for(Button b: Buttons) {
            b.render(g);
        }
        
    
    }

    
    /**
        Custom Buttons
     **/
    private class Button extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
        
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int width, height, x, y, border_radius;
        private String btnText;
        private Font font;
        private Color fontColor;
        /*
         *  Blue    = (126,172,255)
         *  Red     = (255,126,126)
         *  Green   = (179,255,126)
         *  Purple  = (243,126,255) 
         */
        private Color btnColor;
        private Color hoverColor;
        private boolean mouseEntered, mouseClicked, mouseReleased;

        
        public Button(int x, int y, int width, int height, String btnText, int borderRadius, Color defaultColor, Color hoverColor, Color fontColor) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.btnText = btnText;
            this.border_radius = borderRadius;
            this.btnColor = defaultColor;
            this.font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 15);
            this.fontColor = fontColor;
            
            addMouseListener(this);
            
            mouseEntered = mouseClicked = mouseReleased = false;
            
        }
        
        public void update() {
            /*if((Game.lastMouse_clickX > this.x && Game.lastMouse_clickX < this.x + this.width)
            && (Game.lastMouse_clickY > this.y && Game.lastMouse_clickY < this.y + this.height)) {
                System.out.println("Clicked on button");
            }*/
            
        }
        
        
        public void render(Graphics2D g) {
            printBtnText(g);
        }
        
        public void printBtnText(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setColor(this.btnColor);
            g.fillRoundRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.border_radius, this.border_radius);
            g.setColor(this.fontColor);
            g.setFont(this.font);
            g.drawString(this.btnText, this.x+(this.width/this.btnText.length()), this.y+25);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { this.mouseClicked = true; System.out.println("Clicked");}

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { this.mouseReleased = false; System.out.println("Pressed");}

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { this.mouseReleased = true; System.out.println("Released");}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { this.mouseEntered = true; System.out.println("Mouse entered"); }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { this.mouseEntered = false; System.out.println("exited");}

        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Java custom button, extended Jcomponent

It may extend JComponent, but it is not a component.

To use a component you need to create an instance of the component and add it to a JPanel.

Instead you are just rendering some graphics onto a panel.

To create a real component:

1. custom painting is done in the paintComponent() method
2. painting is done relative to (0, 0) of the component
3. you need to override the getPreferredSize() method

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples to get you started.